# Bayesian vs Frequentist

Tags: probability, bayesian

In my understanding,  Bayesians view probability as a measure of subjective belief, based on prior beliefs and then use Bayes update rule. Incorporating these elements, they calculate posterior probabilities, which represent the updated beliefs after considering the data. For example, if I want to calculate the p of getting heart disease, I will start with some prior knowledge about the usual p of the population getting heart disease – say, 1 in 5 people do. Then, suppose I get diagnosed with heart palpitations, which would then update my prior belief.

Frequentists, on the other hand, view probability as objective parameters, where observed frequencies are related to the behavior of past events in repeated experiments.

My question is, isn't the Frequentist view just the prior , but without the update in the Bayesian approach? So in the example above, the frequentist way to calculate the chances of getting heart disease would just use the observed p of the population getting heart disease, so 1 in 5 people, without incorporating the new information from the diagnoses. In other words, isn't the way that Bayesians start with the initial priors, exactly the frequentist approach? If I am wrong, please provide a more clear counter example. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The differences between the two approaches are very well documented online, there's little one could hope to add to that debate in a short response.  Tht said, Frequentists certainly do not ignore new information.  They might interpret it differently from the way a Bayesian would. Informally, I'd say that the core difference is that Frequentists believe that there is a true probability underlying the observations and Bayesians are more interested in the subjective views of it.

Comment: [this informal discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31867/bayesian-vs-frequentist-interpretations-of-probability) isn't bad, in my view.

Comment: You have misunderstood the frequentist approach in your example. A frequentist would seek to estimate both the unconditional probability of getting heart disease AND the probability of getting heart disease conditional on already having heart palpitations. Which estimate to apply depends on whether or not the person has palpitations at the time. Obviously, in a real world application features such as age and sex are also relevant. Btw, frequentists update when more data becomes available.